# return row in form of dataframe which contains some word in a particular column

Tags: python

I want to get such a row in a dataframe which contains multiple search criteria.
For Example
path               description
c:/data            he is a good boy
d:/data            rabin is a good boy
e:/data            he is good
f:/data            he is a boy

I want to get all the rows  in a form of dataframe which contains both of ('good','boy')
retun should be 
c:/data  He is a good boy
d:/data  rabin is a good boy

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Where are you reading this data from? What is the input and desired output : not in plain sentences but some formatted way will be nice.

Comment: please try some approaches and if you fail or struck with some code post here ,they will suggest ideas

Comment: APIData=pd.read_csv('ResultCSV.csv',encoding ='latin1')
reducedLine=['policy','details']


for line in APIData["API Summary"]:
    if all(word in line for word in reducedLine):
        print(line)


it is working fine but I am not able to correspoing other column other than API summary

Answer (score 1):

Let's go step by step.

Consider you have the dataframe as below:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'path': ['c:/data', 'd:/data', 'e:/data', 'f:/data'],
    'description': ['he is a good boy', 'rabin is a good boy', 'he is good', 'he is a boy']
})
df
```

```
    description         path
0   he is a good boy    c:/data
1   rabin is a good boy d:/data
2   he is good          e:/data
3   he is a boy         f:/data
```

This is how you get what you want:

```py
df[df['description'].str.contains('good') & df['description'].str.contains('boy')]
```

```
    description         path
0   he is a good boy    c:/data
1   rabin is a good boy d:/data
```

Comment: No worries, please accept my answer if it worked for you! Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

I make this for you... Not tested.

```
def find_intrastr_column_df(df, column_name, list_of_str_to_find):
    """
    Loop in a pandas dataframe, trying to find all rows 
    that contains the listed words in a particular column and 
    return a selected dataframe only with the rows founded.

    df: Pandas Dataframe
    column_name: String. Columns name
    list_of_str_to_find: List. List of String of words to find.
    """

    list_rows_find = []

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        cell_value = row[column_name]
        # ignore nan values
        if cell_value != cell_value:
            break
        else:
            pass

        found = True
        for str in list_of_str_to_find:
            if str not in cell_value:
                found = False
                break
            else:
                pass

        if found:
            list_rows_find.append(index)
        else:
            pass

    df_selected = df.loc[list_rows_find,:]
    return df_selected
```

Comment: x=find_intrastr_column_df(df, 'Description', list_of_str_to_find)
print(x)

Showing error as :    if str not in row[column_name]:

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: Yes.. This code also working ... if there is a blank data in a column .. in that case exception is coming.. thank you so much for your support.

Comment: friend... I edited the code to ignore nan values. I hope that help you.